# Accessing earlier values in odeint

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, odeint

I'm having some trouble using odeint function from scipy. I'm translating a discrete system into a continuous one, but some equation in the discrete model requires that I access the previous value of a variable that I'm currently integrating. How could I translate this behaviour?

```
import numpy as np
days_of_prediction = 15
N = 100
discrete_S0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_I0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_Q0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_H0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_D0 = np.zeros((days_of_prediction, 1))
discrete_S0[0] = 99
discrete_I0[0] = 1
discrete_Q0[0] = 0
discrete_H0[0] = 0
discrete_D0[0] = 0
v=0.1
alpha = 0.3
gamma = 1/21
psi = 0.2
k_h=0.1
k_q=0.1
eta_h=0.3
eta_q=0.3
for t in range(days_of_prediction - 1):
    discrete_S0[t + 1] = discrete_S0[t] - v * discrete_S0[t] * 
discrete_I0[t] / (N - discrete_Q0[t] - discrete_H0[t] - discrete_D0[t])
    discrete_I0[t + 1] = discrete_I0[t] + v * discrete_S0[t] * discrete_I0[t] / (N - discrete_Q0[t] - discrete_H0[t] - discrete_D0[t]) - gamma * discrete_I0[t] - alpha * discrete_I0[t] - psi * discrete_I0[t]
    discrete_Q0[t + 1] = discrete_Q0[t] + alpha * discrete_I0[t] - eta_q * discrete_Q0[t] - k_h *discrete_Q0[t] + k_q * discrete_H0[t]
    discrete_H0[t + 1] = discrete_H0[t] + psi * discrete_I0[t] - eta_h * discrete_H0[t] + k_h * discrete_Q0[t] - k_q * discrete_H0[t] - zeta * discrete_H0[t]
    discrete_R0[t + 1] = discrete_R0[t] + eta_q * discrete_Q0[t] + eta_h * discrete_H0[t]
```

I've posted a snippet of the code, the problem is with the denominator of the first two equations.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In such an equation system, where the previous values of some variables are required in the evolution equation of other variables, you could define your function as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

def fun(RHS, t):

    # get initial boundary condition values
    discrete_S0 = RHS[0]
    discrete_I0 = RHS[1]
    discrete_Q0 = RHS[2]
    discrete_H0 = RHS[3]
    discrete_D0 = RHS[4]

    # calculte rate of respective variables
    discrete_S0dt = - v * discrete_S0 * discrete_I0 / (N - discrete_Q0 - discrete_H0 - discrete_D0)
    discrete_I0dt = v * discrete_S0 * discrete_I0 / (N - discrete_Q0 - discrete_H0 - discrete_D0) - gamma * discrete_I0 - alpha * discrete_I0 - psi * discrete_I0
    discrete_Q0dt = alpha * discrete_I0 - eta_q * discrete_Q0 - k_h *discrete_Q0 + k_q * discrete_H0
    discrete_H0dt = psi * discrete_I0 - eta_h * discrete_H0 + k_h * discrete_Q0 - k_q * discrete_H0 - zeta * discrete_H0
    discrete_D0dt = eta_q * discrete_Q0 + eta_h * discrete_H0

    # Left-hand side of ODE
    LHS = np.zeros([5,])

    LHS[0] = discrete_S0dt
    LHS[1] = discrete_I0dt
    LHS[2] = discrete_Q0dt
    LHS[3] = discrete_H0dt
    LHS[4] = discrete_D0dt

    return LHS
```

Afterward, you can solve it (according to your boundary conditions) as follows:

```py
from scipy.integrate import odeint

v=0.1
alpha = 0.3
gamma = 1/21
psi = 0.2
k_h=0.1
k_q=0.1
eta_h=0.3
eta_q=0.3
y0 = [99, 1, 0, 0, 0]
t = np.linspace(0,13,14)

res = odeint(fun, y0, t)
```

Here y0 is the initial boundary condition for all the variables defined in the function **fun** at t=0. That's why the variable *t* starts from 0.

Also, you can get the result of all the variables as follows:

```py
print(res[:,0])
print(res[:,1])
print(res[:,2])
print(res[:,3])
print(res[:,4])
```